# Different parts of spectrum appearing in the spectral theorem in terms of generalized eigenvectors

Tags: quantum-mechanics, operators, hilbert-space, mathematical-physics, mathematics

**Question:** How to exactly relate both expansions quoted below: Can one be "transformed" into the other? What is the interplay between the various parts of the spectrum appearing?

In Ref. 1 it is stated that

> The most general form of the spectral theorem for an operator $A$
> representing a physical observable is $[\ldots]$ :
> $$ \phi = \sum |a_i)(a_i|\phi\rangle  + \int \mathrm da \,  |a\rangle \langle a|\phi\rangle\quad , \tag{4.4g}$$
> where the sum is over the discrete spectrum and the integral is over the
> (absolutely) continuous spectrum of $A$. It can happen that some or all values $a_i$
> appearing in the sum also appear in the integral. Then they are called
> discrete eigenvalues in the continuous spectrum. If this happens for $a_k$ then $|a_k)$ is still orthogonal to all $|a\rangle$ including $|a_k\rangle$ $[\ldots]$.

Likewise, Ref 2. gives the resolution of the identity in terms of generalized eigenvectors as:

> $[\ldots]$ the question naturally arises whether for every
> self-adjoint operator $A$ and for every $|\psi\rangle$ we can always write
> $$|\psi\rangle = \sum\limits_{\lambda_n\in \sigma_p(A)} \sum\limits_{\alpha\in I(\lambda_n)} |\lambda_n;\alpha\rangle\langle \lambda_n;\alpha|\psi\rangle + \int_{\sigma_c(A)}\mathrm d\lambda \, \sum\limits_{\alpha\in I(\lambda)}|\lambda;\alpha\rangle\langle \lambda;\alpha|\psi\rangle \tag{2.43} \quad . $$
> $ [\ldots]$ The answer to this question is affirmative [if we interpret the integration of $(2.43)$ as a direct integral] for any self-adjoint operator
> which does not have a continuous singular spectrum. This last condition allows
> us to write $\mathrm d\lambda$ in $(2.43)$, instead of having to write another, more general measure.

To elaborate:

I am confused by all the [different parts of the spectrum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decomposition_of_spectrum_(functional_analysis)) involved in both expansions. I know that the spectrum of a self-adjoint operator $A$ is the union of the *point* and *continuous* spectrum: $\sigma(A)= \sigma_p(A) \, \cup\,  \sigma_c(A)$, where these sets are disjoint. Thus, in the expansion of Ref. 2, I think there should be no point of the spectrum which appears both in the sum and in the integral - and embedded eigenvalues are taken care of already by "putting them" in the sum.$^\ddagger$

In Ref.1 the author somehow splits the spectrum in the *discrete* $\sigma_d(A)\subset \sigma_p(A)$ and *absolutely continuous* $\sigma_{ac}(A)$ spectrum.  Is this really correct? As far as I understand, the [discrete spectrum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discrete_spectrum_(mathematics)) consists of eigenvalues which are also isolated. So there cannot be any point from $\sigma(A)$ in its neighborhood and the integration thus would be somehow meaningless, no? Perhaps the author means the *pure point* spectrum $\sigma_{pp}(A) = \bar \sigma_p(A)$ instead of $\sigma_d(A)$? In any case, that a point appears in both the sum and the integral can only happen if both parts are not disjoint.

But do these points belong to the point or continuous spectrum then?
This is indeed very confusing, since both parts of the spectrum are disjoint (as stated above) and thus, a point in the spectrum either corresponds to a genuine eigenvector (and therefore is an eigenvalue) or to a generalized eigenvector - how can both hold true at the same time?

**Summarizing:** I have the feeling that both expressions must be equivalent and hence it should be possible to transform one into the other. But I don't really understand the relations between all the various parts of the spectrum enough to clearly see how both expressions are related. In particular, I don't understand how a single point appears with both an eigenvector and a generalized vector in the first expansion.

---

**References:**

1. *Arno Bohm. Quantum Mechanics: Foundations and Applications. Springer, third edition.* Chapter I.4, page 12.
2. *Quantum Mechanics I. Galindo and Pascual. Springer.* Chapter 2, page 48.

$^\ddagger$ See also [this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/708654/resolution-of-the-identity-of-operator-with-mixed-spectrum) related question. The answer there works with the notion of spectral measures instead of generalized eigenvectors, tho.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The two types of spectra, $\sigma_c$ and $\sigma_p$, are *disjont*; so that the first statement you quoted is mathematically speaking **wrong**: $\sigma_c(A) \cap \sigma_p(A)=\emptyset$.
But the book seems to be not very mathematically minded so a bit vague statements are definitely tolerable! Furthermore,  one should take the fact into account that each element of the continuous spectrum has *zero (spectral) measure* (see (3) in the proposition below).

The second decomposition you quote is correct. However the *discrete spectrum* is made of isolated points **whose eignespace is finite-dimensional**.
This second type of decomposition refers to the decomposition of the spectrum into **discrete** (the one said above) and and **essential** spectrum (its complement).
A third decomposition you mention is the one into **absolutely continuous spectrum** and **singular spectrum**.

Notice that isolated points of the spectrum are always part of the point spectrum, but the *vice versa* is false.
I do not understand well your remark about issues with integration for points in the discrete spectrum: see the last item of the following proposition where $ {\cal B}(\mathbb{R})$ is the $\sigma$-algebra of Borel sets in $\mathbb{R}$.

**Proposition**. *Let $A: D(A) \to H$ be a selfadjoint operator and let $P: {\cal B}(\mathbb{R}) \to \mathfrak{B}(H)$ be the projection-valued measure (also known as  spectral measure) of $A$ so that
$$A = \int_{\mathbb{R}} \lambda dP(\lambda)\:.$$
The following facts are true for $\lambda \in \mathbb{R}$*.

*(1) The support of $P$ (i.e., the complement of the largest open set $A\subset \mathbb{R}$ such that $P_A=0$) is $\sigma(A)$.*

*(2) $\lambda \in \sigma_p(A)$ if and only if $P_{\{\lambda\}} \neq 0$. In that case $P_{\{\lambda\}}$ is the orthogonal projector onto the $\lambda$-eigenspace of $A$.*

*(3) $\lambda \in \sigma_c(A)$ if and only if both conditions are true: (a) $P_{\{\lambda\}}=0$ and (b) $P_{(a,b)}\neq 0$ if $a<b$ and $\lambda \in (a,b)$.*

*(4) If $\lambda$ is an isolated point of $\sigma(A)$ then necessarily $\lambda \in \sigma_p(A)$* and thus $P_{\{\lambda \}}\neq 0$.

(As references I could quote my  books on spectral theory and QM [books on spectral theory](https://link.springer.com/book/10.1007/978-3-319-70706-8) or also  [the more recent one](https://link.springer.com/book/10.1007/978-3-030-18346-2#aboutBook).)

On account  of the proposition, we can re-arrange the integral as
$$A = \sum_{\lambda \in \sigma_p(A)} P_{\{\lambda\}} + \int_{\sigma_c(A)} \lambda dP(\lambda)\:.$$

Comment: Dear Valter, as always, great answer; thank you very much. Do you know/ can you guess what the author of the first quote *means* however (e.g. physically)? I also took the freedom to correct two typos.

Comment: Thanks! I am adding some other commets however...

Comment: Now I am a bit confused: The decomposition in Ref. 2 is correct, no? But if I understand you correctly, you say they don't decompose in point and continuous (what they actually indicate by their notation) but rather in discrete and essential spectrum? Or does your comment not refer to Ref. 2 but instead you mean that one could in principle do this, i.e. there are, as you point out, at least three possible decompositions of the spectrum?

Comment: Yes it is correct, but there the issue is subtle. There the book is considering the fact if the measure used in the continuous part is proportional to the Lebesgue measure or not.

Comment: The the statement "for any self-adjoint operator which does not have a continuous singular spectrum" refers to this issue. If a continuous singular part is present, the integral cannot be written with a $d\lambda$ at the end: thati is the Lebersgue measure! There exist "continuous" measure that are not proportional to the Lebesgue one. In the decomposition I wrote in my answer, this problem is not addressed.

Comment: I see, thank you. So to summarize: I can decompose the spectrum into point and continuous part and write the decomposition in Ref. 2. as long as this condition holds (which, as far as I know, however is not always given in physical contexts). The decomposition in Ref. 1 however is mathematically wrong (but I still don't see why one should write this if there is no physical content to it). Lastly, and this is also what I also understood from your answer to the linked question, it seems much easier to use spectral measures to formulate the theorem.

Comment: I agree with your analysis. The decomposition I used in my answer is the most natural and elementary one. However, for several specific reasons, it could be intersting/useful to study the interplay of the part of the spectral measure *different from isolated points*  and the Lebesgue measure.

Comment: Notice that the standard *point spectrum* may be a dense set or even an open set. So "point spectrum" is a misleading name. THis partially justifies the further types of decompositions one encounters in the literature on the subject.

Comment: Okay, thanks again for your help, much appreciated! I again took the freedom to change a single word, hope its okay. But for me it makes the message clearer.

Comment: I think that this is not quite right... about the "definitional" disjointness of discrete and continuous spectrum. Sure, we can make it be "a definition", but, operationally, (as with a spectral "calculus") this would not be sustainable... But, ok, conventions...

Comment: @paul garrett. Sorry I do not understand your remark, could you tell something more?

Comment: Dear Valter, sorry to bother you again, but I have one more question, if you allow (I can also ask a separate, new question if a short answer is not possible). I've found your very helpful answer [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/263494/properties-of-spectrum-of-a-self-adjoint-operator-on-a-separable-hilbert-space). In the light of the example $(2)$ and the example you give in the comments - is it possible to write down the expansion of Ref. 2 here? Or are these cases where the continuous singular spectrum is non-empty or some other, hidden, assumption fail? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hi @Tobias Fünke  Please ask a separate question since this issue is quite complicated and I am not sure to understand well.

Comment: @ValterMoretti this is an amazing answer! I wonder: could you say a few words about how the second term in your expression, the integral over $\sigma_{c}(T)$, is translated to the informal physicist point of view, when they write the integral term in (4.4g)? In other words, what is the connection between the projection valued measure $\lambda dP(\lambda)$ as a "measure" $da |a\rangle\langle a|\phi\rangle$? What is the philosophy of writing the former as the latter?

Comment: Sorry I am too busy. However the rigorous formalism to handle these ideas by physicists is the notion of Rigged Hilbert space also known as Gelfand's formalism. Alternatively an almost equivalent rigorous formalism is the direct integral .

Answer (score 1):

Ah, there are many natural situations in which some large part of the discrete/eigenvalue spectrum of a (bounded, self-adjoint) Hilbert space operator lies inside the continuous spectrum. Also for unbounded self-adjoint operators.

That is, the spectral measure can be a sum of Lebesgue-type measure on some intervals, *plus* some Dirac measures on the discrete spectrum.

The case I'm familiar with is the Laplace-Beltrami operator (or its resolvent, if we insist on something bounded) on the modular curve, where there are infinitely-many "cuspforms" in the discrete spectrum, with eigenvalues going to $-\infty$, as well as continuous spectrum going from $-1/4$ to $-\infty$ (depending on one's normalization of the Laplacian). So there is no doubt that the continuous spectrum can contain (infinitely many) eigenvalues.

So-called "imbedded spectrum".

EDIT: Yes, many sources seem to *define* continuous spectrum in a way that makes it seem that it cannot also contain any discrete spectrum. And, yes, essentially since the Lebesgue measure of single points is $0$, this doesn't actually wreck anything. But it is misleading, I think.

To give a concrete example, consider the ("multiplication") operator on $L^2(\mathbb R)$ given by $Tf(x)=f(x)\cdot h(x)$, where $h$ is identically $0$ on $(-\infty,0]$, is identically $1$ on $[0,2]$, rises linearly to $5$ on $[2,3]$, decays linearly to $0$ on $[3,4]$, and is $0$ on $[4,+\infty)$.

The real-valued-ness means that this multiplication operator is self-adjoint.

The flat part with value $1$ means that any function supported on $[0,2]$ is an eigenvector with eigenvalue $1$. (Also, any function supported on $(-\infty,0]\cup [4,+\infty)$ is an eigenvector with eigenvalue $0$.) Since the graph on $[2,4]$ has no horizontal-flat parts, there are no other eigenvalues. But/and the fact that the range of the function restricted to $[2,4]$ is $[0,5]$ means that there are (Weyl-style) "approximate eigenvectors" for all $\lambda\in[0,5]$, which (small theorem) implies that the continuous spectrum is (well, to be precise, *contains*) $[0,5]$, in a natural way.

Yes, the eigenvalues $1$ and $0$ are also in $[0,5]$.

(So, the spectral measure is Lebesgue measure on $[0,5]$, plus Dirac measures at $1$ and $0$.)

Comment: Dear Paul, thanks for your answer. Unfortunately I don't really understand it. Could you elaborate what exactly it means that the discrete spectrum lies inside the continuous spectrum? As I tried to elaborate in my post, I thought that the point and continuous spectrum are disjoint  - so how is this possible?